# VBscript, For each loop and Msgbox in the end

Tags: vbscript

I´m working with VBScript that ie. displays and saves computer hardware info into txt file. My VBscript do some another stuff too ie. modifies some XML files. Now I want use opensource hardware monitoring software so I can log temps, voltages etc. while i´m running torture tests for the computer. The monitoring software is logging results in CSV format so I have first find out if CSV file exists in source folder because name is always different, and then rename it with computer name (I use inputbox to give that name and you can´t see it in code given below). Anyway I want to copy CSV file to another destination. Problem is that if CSV file is not found in source folder, then that MsgBox pop-ups as many times that there are files in the dest. folder. I know that the problem is in "For Each" loop but don´t know how can I bypass that if CSV file doesn´t exist. I want that MsgBox shows itself only once if CSV file doesn´t exists. Can anybody help me with this one?

```
dim fso, oshell, strProfilePath, oTFldr, fname, WshShell, txt
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strProfilePath = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

If fso.FolderExists(strProfilePath & "\Desktop\Tests\Software\") then
Set oTFldr = fso.getfolder(strProfilePath & "\Desktop\Tests\Software\")
Else
MsgBox "Software folder doesn´t exists!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly  
End If

For each ofile in oTFldr.Files
If UCase(fso.GetExtensionName(ofile.Name)) = "CSV" then
ofile.name = Compname & ".CSV"
fso.Copyfile strProfilePath & "\Desktop\Tests\Software\" & Compname & ".CSV", "C:\"
exit for
else
MsgBox "Didn´t find any CSV file!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
End If
Next
```

Comment: Remove the Else clause from the If statement inside the For Each loop. Create a variable name Found and set it to False right before the For Each. Right before the Exit For statement, set Found to True. After the For Each Next structure, use an If statement to see if Found is still False. If it is then use the MsgBox to indicate you didn't find any CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

```
For each ofile in oTFldr.Files
   If UCase(fso.GetExtensionName(ofile.Name)) = "CSV" then
      ofile.name = Compname & ".CSV"
      fso.Copyfile strProfilePath & "\Desktop\Tests\Software\" & Compname & ".CSV", "C:\"
      exit for
   'else
   '    MsgBox "Didn´t find any CSV file!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
   End If
Next
```